# How would I say "After many days of rain" in Italian?

Tags: translation, phrase-request

I am preparing a new entry about the 1966 flood in Firenze for my blog. I want to say "after many days of rain". Is there a good way to translate this phrase, please? I am not sure if it's straight forward or it more complicated?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because basic translations of a very simple phrase are not what the SE sites are created for. Please see [this answer on Meta](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/12/are-questions-about-translation-requests-on-topic) to understand what you would need to change to make this question on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate it as

> Dopo tanti giorni di pioggia.