# Present perfect vs simple past from a geographical perspective

Tags: regional, history, tenses, past-tense

This [question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2255/when-does-passato-prossimo-become-passato-remoto) deals with the usage of *passato prossimo* vs *passato remoto* from a grammatical perspective and the answers cover the subject quite extensively. There is a hint at the geographical differences which are quite marked with respect to their  common everyday  usage.
My Sicilian  friends would normally say "Che disse?" to refer to something just mentioned, while in Milan you are likely to hear "Dove sei stato in vacanza l'anno scorso?".
What are the likely reasons for this remarkable difference in usage between the two tenses from a regional perspective?

---

The same question in Italian, expressed in a different way (it's not a translation of the previous text):

Più o meno chiunque che abbia vissuto in più parti d'Italia ha sicuramente notato che, nell'Italiano parlato, c'è [una spiccata differenza geografica nella formazione del tempo passato](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2255/when-does-passato-prossimo-become-passato-remoto).

In Italia settentrionale, il passato prossimo è essenzialmente l'unico tempo usato (e.g. *Nel dodicesimo secolo la Chiesa ha attraversato un periodo di riforma*). In Italia meridionale invece la situazione si inverte, e il passato remoto domina (non do esempi venendo io stesso dal nord Italia, se qualcuno potesse inserirne uno ne sarei grato).

Ora, il passato prossimo è un tempo relativamente recente: inesistente in latino è una delle caratteristiche più tipiche della [Sprachbund europea](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Average_European), e si è andato ad innestare sopra il passato remoto, discendente diretto del *perfectum* latino,

> **Q** Per quale motivo il passato prossimo ha questa ineguale distribuzione d'uso nella penisola italiana?

Riesco a pensare a due spiegazioni: forse il passato prossimo è giunto "dal nord" attraverso le alpi e semplicemente non ha fatto in tempo a penetrare fino al sud Italia, o forse la differenza d'uso è dovuta alle dominazioni straniere che hanno influenzato fortemente le differenze culturali in Italia. Ma non ho prove in una direzione o nell'altra e sospetto che la vera risposta non sia nessuna delle due.

Comment: Mi sono presa la libertà di aggiungere il [testo di @DenisNardin](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9555/qual-%c3%a8-la-causa-della-divisione-geografica-tra-il-passato-prossimo-e-il-passato) a questa domanda perché mi sembra che contenga aspetti interessanti.

Comment: Per il fenomeno dell'uso del passato remoto nel sud, l'ipotesi dell'isolamento geografico mi sembra plausibile. Accade una cosa molto simile in spagnolo: per esprimere, per esempio, "sei venuto presto" in America Latina o nelle isole Canarie direbbero "viniste pronto", mentre nella Penisola iberica si direbbe "has venido pronto".

Comment: In catalano, perlomeno in quello che si parla in Catalogna, il passato remoto non si usa quasi più. Tutt'al più si può leggere la terza persona in qualche testo formale, ma la prima persona singolare ("jo cantí", "jo sabí", ecc.) è praticamente estinta. La ragione è che di solito usiamo una perifrasi verbale per esprimere l'idea di un passato remoto. Per esempio, invece di "cantàrem" diciamo "vam cantar", con il significato di "cantammo".

Answer (score 8):

A fantastic question. I reserve to edit and further add details to this answer as soon as I get some.

There are many texts that acknowledge the differences in the usage of the past that you mentioned, but none of them digs into the reasons why this difference exists.

At the moment, I have found [this](http://www.verbum-analectaneolatina.hu/pdf/12-2-24.pdf) reference, which links the differences in the usage of the past to the heritage of the Greek influence in the southern part of Italy, reporting a similarity between the tendency of using *passato remoto* in southern dialects and Greek.

Comment: I would suggest also to investigate on the influx of Spanish in southern regions (but from a quick research I found only this debate on wordreference http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1200256).