# Qual è la causa della divisione geografica tra il passato prossimo e il passato remoto?

Tags: history, tenses

Più o meno chiunque che abbia vissuto in più parti d'Italia ha sicuramente notato che, nell'Italiano parlato, c'è [una spiccata differenza geografica nella formazione del tempo passato](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2255/when-does-passato-prossimo-become-passato-remoto).

In Italia settentrionale, il passato prossimo è essenzialmente l'unico tempo usato (e.g. *Nel dodicesimo secolo la Chiesa ha attraversato un periodo di riforma*). In Italia meridionale invece la situazione si inverte, e il passato remoto domina (non do esempi venendo io stesso dal nord Italia, se qualcuno potesse inserirne uno ne sarei grato).

Ora, il passato prossimo è un tempo relativamente recente: inesistente in latino è una delle caratteristiche più tipiche della [Sprachbund europea](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Average_European), e si è andato ad innestare sopra il passato remoto, discendente diretto del *perfectum* latino,

> **Q** Per quale motivo il passato prossimo ha questa ineguale distribuzione d'uso nella penisola italiana?

Riesco a pensare a due spiegazioni: forse il passato prossimo è giunto "dal nord" attraverso le alpi e semplicemente non ha fatto in tempo a penetrare fino al sud Italia, o forse la differenza d'uso è dovuta alle dominazioni straniere che hanno influenzato fortemente le differenze culturali in Italia. Ma non ho prove in una direzione o nell'altra e sospetto che la vera risposta non sia nessuna delle due.

Comment: Ecco qualche esempio del passato remoto: [“E la porta magari non la chiudi dietro? Non te la chiudi? Io la chiuderei, eh? Io la chiuderei, perché questa è bastarda! Ecco. Io lo **dis** … Io lo **dissi**! Io lo **dissi**!”](https://youtu.be/-ugMe5WW7Aw?t=12m21s) — [“Come vi **scrissi** anche su Facebook (…) avevo prodotto, ma non l’ho mai pubblicato, un mini-video …”](https://youtu.be/9uleD9D-CU8?t=1m38s) — [“… come vi **dissi**, *Gal٭Gun VR* era un gioco perfetto come gioco per VIVE.”](https://youtu.be/3g16MWFYvH4?t=6m36s)

Comment: «Il passato remoto è giunto "dal nord"»: vuoi dire il passato prossimo?

Comment: @Charo Oops. Corretto

Comment: Per il secondo fenomeno, l'ipotesi dell'isolamento geografico mi sembra plausibile. Accade una cosa molto simile in spagnolo: per esprimere, per esempio, "sei venuto presto" in America Latina o nelle isole Canarie direbbero "viniste pronto", mentre nella Penisola iberica si direbbe "has venido pronto".

Comment: Forse si tratta di un doppione, ma questa domanda contiene aspetti che penso sia interessante includere nella domanda di @Gio.

Comment: Hmm.... effettivamente sembra un duplicato. La chiudo?

Comment: Peraltro, mi piace la domanda scritta in italiano...

Comment: Forse si potrebbe aggiungere il testo di Denis alla domanda di @Gio. Che ne pensate?

Comment: @DenisNardin: Io aspetterei un po' prima di chiuderla, così possiamo vedere cosa ne pensano gli altri.