# Quando si usa il passato prossimo e quando il passato remoto, davvero?

Tags: word-usage, past-tense

Cercando la descrizione della differenza tra passato prossimo e passato remoto nelle grammatiche si trova spesso l'idea che il passato prossimo vada usato quando l'evento passato è ancora collegato al presente, e il passato remoto se l'evento è percepito come separato.

Vedasi ad esempio [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2255/when-does-passato-prossimo-become-passato-remoto) e i suoi vari riferimenti (e.g. la grammatica di Serianni) o [questa risposta sul sito della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/sulluso-passato-remoto).

Questo non corrisponde minimamente alla mia percezione dell'uso in pratica. È infatti abbastanza riconosciuto che l'uso dei due tempi varii molto su base regionale (cfr. [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2383/present-perfect-vs-simple-past-from-a-geographical-perspective) e l'ultimo paragrafo del già citato articolo sul sito della Crusca). Nella mia esperienza l'uso (anche in contesti semiformali) ha molto più a che vedere con il contesto: il passato remoto tende a esistere principalmente nella lingua scritta, e comunque sempre con un certo valore di "passato narrativo", usato quando si vuole implicare una narrazione. Questo però è un puro aneddoto personale, e sono sicuro che l'esperienza di altre persone è differente.

Mi sembra un po' ridicolo però insegnare agli stranieri l'uso di regole a cui solo una stretta minoranza dei parlanti nativi (che vivono in una striscia via via assottigliantesi del centro Italia) aderisce.

> **Q:** Esiste una fonte che descriva l'uso *vero* della dicotomia tra passato prossimo e passato remoto in pratica, probabilmente facendo divisioni su base regionale dei parlanti?

Comment: [Discussion moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95052/discussion-between-dag-and-denis-nardin).