# trapassato prossimo o trapassato remoto

Tags: past-tense

Salve!
Mi potreste spiegare per piacere le differenze fra queste frasi?

1. Dopo che ebbi scambiato qualche parola con lui, mi venne in mente che ci eravamo già incontrati da qualche parte.
2. Dopo che ebbi scambiato qualche parola con lui, mi venne in mente che ci fummo già incontrati da qualche parte.
3. Dopo che avevo scambiato qualche parola con lui, mi venne in mente che ci eravamo già incontrati da qualche parte.

Grazie in anticipo :)

Comment: Related: [When does passato prossimo become passato remoto?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2255/when-does-passato-prossimo-become-passato-remoto?)